# Can glShaderSource be called to update shader source code after shader compilation fail?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I am currently writing a Shader class, and was curious whether following use case in opengl is valid.

Suppose you added source code (SourceCode) to a shader (specified by handle):

```
void glShaderSource(handle, 1, sourceCode, nullptr);
```

Then you try to compile the shader and it fails.

Is it a valid and/or well tested use case to update sourceCode, call glShaderSource again as above, and recompile?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can compile other shaders after one failed.

> well tested use case

I'm sure it's tested, but nobody does this. Fix your shader before you even start your program, not after.

Comment: "nobody does this" I think the webgl shader toys and all the stuff with interactive shader editors do this all the time

Comment: That still seems fairly niche, but sure, I'll give you that.